# Do switch statements guarantee order?

Tags: c#, switch-statement, hashtable

I have read in various places that `switch` statements with `string` cases can potentially be optimized (by the compiler or the JIT) into hash tables to improve performance. Hash tables with non-perfect hashing functions obviously do not guarantee item order, and so I was wondering:

1. Can the C# compiler or the JIT perform an optimization that converts a `switch` statement to a hash table to provide constant-time performance?
2. Do `switch` statements in C# **guarantee** that the `case`'s are checked in order, from top to bottom?

Comment: The order in which they are checked has no observable effect, so why do you care? Compilers almost never make guarantees about unobservable behavior.

Comment: It is not `C++` `switch`.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I have come across a rather tedious piece of code which contains a large `switch` statements with strings. The creator of the code put the two most common options at the top with the idea that they will usually be checked first, and I was merely wondering whether it was true or not.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: Maybe not *logically* observable, but it could be *physically* observable in that it could change how long it takes to execute. Of course, one should not write code that relies on such implementation-dependent behaviour!

Comment: @MatthewWatson That is pretty much my question - is it defined behavior or is it implementation dependent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no **any guarantee** that the order will be maintained, as this is a *purely compiler implementation detail*, so even if it's would be true now, for `.net 5.1` (say), may be wrong.

`switch/case` construct is made for identifying unique option(s) between different available ones. So, the order does not matter, if not from performance point of view, but even there, it's basically irrelevant, and *if* not, it could not be predicted for the reasons described above.

So just not pay attention to this, and look on other parts of your program, if you're looking for some performance bottlenecks.

Comment: Like I said in another comment, I am merely curious due to a piece of code I came across which did rely on this to improve performance (despite it obviously being minuscule either way). I don't understand why so many people on SO feel the need to answer questions with "You shouldn't even care!".

Comment: @Acidic: "You shouldn't even care", in this case, cause it's not something that depends on you, so you have no any power to affect that behaviour. If you're asking about concrete numbers, I have no them, I never measured this.

Comment: If you do care, replace the switch with an if/elseif cascade.

Comment: I have no power to affect most language features, should I not care about them?

Comment: @MatthewWatson well that is why I'm asking if a `switch` statement guarantees order or not.

Comment: @Acidic: I understand this question is a matter of curiosity, but as I said, I have no any *concrete* number in my hand.